# Have breakpoint print the name of the calling function

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

I'd like to have my breakpoint print the name of the test it's being called from in the console. Is this possible?

Relatedly, can I have a breakpoint condition be dependent on which function got us to the breakpoint?

Comment: `print(#function)`

Comment: That prints the function we're currently in, not the function that called it (the previous function in the call stack). Also it doesn't seem to work as a debugger message. `@#function@` prints `"$__lldb_wrapped_expr_39"`

Comment: Just add it to the other methods as well and you can see which one called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not exactly the "function" name you can use `lldb`'s command to print the call stack as far back as you want.

In Xcode create a breakpoint with a "Debugger Command" action of `bt 2` (the 2 limits the depth of the call stack to print). *If you don't want the breakpoint to actually stop processing also tick the option "Automatically continue…" checkbox at the bottom.*

[image: Setting an lldb command using a breakpoint action]

When the breakpoint is hit you'll see output similar to this in the "Debugger Output" pane in the "Debug Area" at the bottom of your Xcode window.

[image: lldb output from bt]

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000104982fa8 SharingTest`DataManager.loadFromDisk(self=0x000060800005e3f0) at DataManager.swift:66
    frame #1: 0x0000000104998dbe SharingTest`AppDelegate.applicationDidBecomeActive(application=0x00007fe6b9600220, self=0x000060400005b2d0) at AppDelegate.swift:56
```

Comment: Thank you @Craig, that seems great. Also actually answers my question of getting the result I want from the breakpoint and not from code.

Comment: Make the action debugger command as `bt 1` and you see the current method with parameter values

Answer (score 1):

If you add a string parameter with a default value of `#function`, it gets filled in with the calling function name:

```
func bar(_ funcName:String = #function) {
    print("called from function", funcName)
}

func foo() {
    bar()
}

foo()
```

That prints "called from function foo()"

The only problem with that is if you pass it an actual string value, that overrides the default value so:

```
func foo() {
    bar("snort")
}
```

That prints "called from function snort"